# Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '(string | number | boolean)[][]

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I've been writing a TypeScript code (Office Script) with the help of chat GPT (I'm really new to this language). I first started with two different scripts that worked and then started merging them together to do all operations in one single script.

I'm having an issue here it seems with the way I'm using a variable. On line 71, it says that Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '(string | number | boolean)[][]'.

What is strange however, is that on line 56 this is exactly done that way with the operator for the other variable and there are no issues for that one.

The key difference that the variable `urlValues` goes through a first block of code that performs an operation that the variable `linkedinUrlValues` does not get on purpose.

I am not sure what's going on

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the current worksheet.
    const worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    // Get the table in this worksheet, we asume the first table is the one
    const table = worksheet.getTables()[0];

    // Get the website column inside the table.
    const websiteColumn = table.getColumnByName('Website');
    if (!websiteColumn) {
        console.log("No 'Website' column found in the table !");
        return;
    }

    // Get the Linkedin URL column inside the table.
    const linkedinColumn = table.getColumnByName('Linkedin Company Page URL');
    if (!linkedinColumn) {
        console.log("No 'Linkedin Company Page URL' column found in the table");
        return;
    }

    // Get the index of the website column
    const websiteColumnIndex = websiteColumn.getIndex();

    // Get the index of the Linkedin URL column
    const linkedinColumnIndex = linkedinColumn.getIndex();

    // Get all the values in the column.
    let urlRange = websiteColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let urlValues = urlRange.getValues();

    // Get all values in the Linkedin URL column
    let linkedinUrlRange = linkedinColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let linkedinUrlValues = linkedinUrlRange.getValues();

    // Truncate the URLs to remove trailing text
    for (let i = 0; i < urlValues.length; i++) {
        let url = urlValues[i][0] as string;
        // Split the URL by '/'
        let urlParts = url.split("/");

        // Check if the URL starts with 'http://' or 'https://'
        if (urlParts[0].startsWith('http')) {
            let domainAndTld = urlParts[2]; // The domain and TLD will be the third part after splitting by '/'
            // rebuild the url to only include the protocol (http:// or https://), domain and TLD
            url = urlParts[0] + '//' + domainAndTld;
        } else {
            // if the url does not start with 'http' assume the first part is the domain and TLD
            url = urlParts[0];
        }

        urlValues[i][0] = url;
    }

    // Trim http://, https://, www. from starting of the string.
    for (let i = 0; i < urlValues.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < urlValues[0].length; j++) {
            let url = urlValues[i][j];

            //Check if the value is a string and looks like a URL
            if (typeof url == "string" && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
                url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").replace("www.", "");

                //update the value in the original values array
                urlValues[i][j] = url;
            }
        }
    }

    // Trim http://, https://, www. from starting of the string of the Linkedin URLs
    for (let i = 0; i < linkedinUrlValues; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < linkedinUrlValues[0].length; j++) {
            let linkedurl = linkedinUrlValues[i][j];

            //Check if the value is a string and looks like a URL
            if (typeof linkedurl == "string" && (linkedurl.startsWith("http://") || linkedurl.startsWith("https://"))) {
                linkedurl = linkedurl.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").replace("www.", "");

                //update the value in the original values array
                linkedinUrlValues[i][j] = linkedurl;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add a new column to the right of the "Website" column
    const domainColumn = table.addColumn(websiteColumnIndex + 1);
    domainColumn.setName('Domain names')

    // Add a new colum to the right of the 'Linkedin Company Page URL" column
    const linkedinDomainColumn = table.addColumn(linkedinColumnIndex + 1);
    linkedinDomainColumn.setName('Linkedin Domains')

    // Get range of the new "Comain names" column
    let domainRange = domainColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();

    // Get range of the new "Linkedin Domains" column
    let linkedindomainRange = linkedinDomainColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();

    // Update the Domain names column range with new values.
    domainRange.setValues(urlValues);

    // Update the Linkedin Domains column range with the ne values
    linkedindomainRange.setValues(linkedinUrlValues);
}
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < linkedinUrlValues; i++)` should be `for (let i = 0; i < linkedinUrlValues.length; i++)`. It's a typo.

Comment: Ahh. Yes! This works now. Thank you.

I'd like to the the opportunity to ask a follow up question. 
Towards the end I've got this code block

    `// Add a new colum to the right of the 'Linkedin Company Page URL" column
    const linkedinDomainColumn = table.addColumn(linkedinColumnIndex + 1);
    linkedinDomainColumn.setName('Linkedin Domains')`

However, what I notice is that when the script runs, its create the column on the left of the Linkedin Company Page URL column, not the right side.

Am I also having a typo somewhere?

Comment: Please ask a separate question. Feel free to include a [mcve] with the emphasis on minimal

Comment: "I'd like to the the opportunity to ask a follow up question"  While someone might try to help you here, followup questions in comments or edited into questions are not appropriate.  [Please post a new question instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/2887218).

Comment: Ok, will do that.